# Call a child method from parent MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a user control and inside that two user controls as below -

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding UC1Visible}">
        <controls:UC1  x:Name="UC1"></controls:UC1>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding UC2Visible}">
        <controls:UC2  x:Name="UC2"></controls:UC2>
    </StackPanel>
```

i have two view models like UC1ViewModel and UC2ViewModel. I have a method ResetData in both of these view models. In Parent user control viewmodel i have a switch condition from where i am displaying these controls accordingly. i want to call that ResetData method in this switch condition so that can reset data while switching the options. How to do that.

i tried -

```
new UC1Viewmodel.ResetData();
new UC1Viewmode2.ResetData();
```

by calling this it comes to debug but did not reset the data.May be some datacontext issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `DataContext` of your custom controls like this

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding UC1Visible}">
    <controls:UC1  x:Name="UC1" DataContext="{Binding UC1ViewModel}"></controls:UC1>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding UC2Visible}">
    <controls:UC2  x:Name="UC2" DataContext="{Binding UC2ViewModel}></controls:UC2>
</StackPanel>
```

supposing to have in your ParentViewModel 2 properties named `UC1ViewModel` and `UC2ViewModel` of type `UC1ViewModel` and `UC2ViewModel` respectively.
If you didn't to that your custom controls' `DataContext` will be your ParentViewModel.

Instead of manually switch the user control visibility you may consider replacing them with 2 `DataTemplate` and  `Trigger` for switching among them.